# Populate second selection on the basis of first selection in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, selection

I am stuck into a Management Web Application where I want user to **choose** a **specific** **service** from **selection** and on the basis of selected service I want to **populate** the **other selection** with **sub services**.  Now I searched the web where I didn't find any code nor any logic. I also want the **user** to **change his service and it should change the subservice automatically**. And I want to do it in JSP. I have done this is Java Swing Application using Item State Changed but I have no idea about JSP. This is my first question on Stack Overflow so if I am wrong somewhere kindly point it out

Answer (score 0):

JSP isn't the tool that will allow you to do this.  JSP is all server-side - that is, by the time the user is interacting with the page, all the JSP logic will be done.

You'll need some code running on the client side - probably some Javascript (with an AJAX call).